# Shared hosting setup for on Apache for Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, shared-hosting

We're looking for a clean and isolated way to host several Django sites on a single Apache with vhosts on Ubuntu 14.04.

Following the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode
and [Where should WSGIPythonPath point in my virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832777/where-should-wsgipythonpath-point-in-my-virtualenv/27881007#27881007) , we set the following setup :

Have a global virtualenv for mod_wsgi

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 /home/admin/vhosts_venv
. vhosts_venv/bin/activate
pip install mod-wsgi

sudo /home/admin/vhosts_venv/bin/mod_wsgi-express install-module
sudo vi /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.load
```

added :

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi-py34.cpython-34m.so
```

Then have a vhost venv and a basic app :

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 /home/admin/vhost1_venv
. vhost1_venv/bin/activate
pip install Django
pip install PyMySQL

django-admin startproject vhost1
cd vhost1
python manage.py startapp main
```

Setup host resolution with :

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

updated :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost vhost1.example.com
```

Setup Apache vhost with :

```
<VirtualHost vhost1.example.com:80>
  ServerName vhost1.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhost1_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhost1_access.log combined

  WSGIProcessGroup  vhost1.example.com
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/vhost1/vhost1/wsgi.py process-group=vhost1.example.com
  WSGIDaemonProcess vhost1.example.com user=www-data group=www-data threads=25 python-path=/home/admin/vhost1:/home/admin/vhost1_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages:/home/admin/vhosts_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages

  <Directory /home/admin/vhost1>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      <IfVersion < 2.3>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
      </IfVersion>
      <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
      </IfVersion>
    </Files>
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Enabled everything with :

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi_express
sudo a2ensite vhost1
sudo service apache2 restart
```

When testing it, we get 2 answers for a single curl request, delivered in 2 timing (sometime like 0.5s between each) :

```
curl vhost1.example.com
```

> It worked! Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.
>
> Of course, you haven't actually done any work yet. Next, start your
>   first app by running python manage.py startapp [app_label].
>
> You're seeing this message because you have DEBUG = True in your
>   Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!

Directly followed by :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at vhost1.example.com Port 80

In `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, we get :

> [Mon Aug 15 15:37:42.754139 2016] [core:notice] [pid 18622:tid
>   140151787534208] AH00051: child pid 18717 exit signal Segmentation
>   fault (11) , possible coredump in /etc/apache2

and in `/var/log/apache2/vhost1_access.log` :

> 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2016:15:37:42 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 2593 "-" "curl/7.35.0"

How to set it up correctly?

Comment: If you are using mod_wsgi 4.5.4, remove it and install 4.5.3 instead. An issue affecting Python 3 got introduced in 4.5.4 which causes processes to crash if application sends anything to stdout/stderr using ``print`` or Python logging module. There will be a 4.5.5 release today which rolls back the change while solution is found.

Comment: Another source of crashes is C extensions which don't work in sub interpreters. Use ``application-group=%{GLOBAL}`` option with ``WSGIScriptAlias``. You also don't need the ``WSGIProcessGroup`` directive as you are using the ``process-group`` option to ``WSGIScriptAlias``.

Comment: The tracking of Python virtual environment ``site-packages`` directories is also suspect. Should only refer to one and preferable to use ``python-home`` option to denote top of virtual environment and not use ``python-path`` to ``site-packages`` directory in it.

Comment: Wow ... upgrading from 4.5.4 to 4.5.5 fixed it.

Comment: For the 2nd comment : When removing WSGIProcessGroup and setting `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/vhost1/vhost1/wsgi.py process-group=vhost1.example.com application-group=%{GLOBAL}` , I get the error while restarting Apache2 : `WSGI process group not yet configured.`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Regarding 3rd comment, we need 2 venv for a shared hosting. One has the mod-wsgi (shared for every hosted sites). The second has the site's packages. I'm not sure to understand the syntax you mean. Could you write it down please?
Thanks

Comment: Move the ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` directive before the ``WSGIScriptAlias`` directive. As to your virtual environments, what you are describing doesn't make sense. So long as the per site virtual environment was created off the same Python installation mod_wsgi was built for, that is enough. You do not need to also reference the Python installation mod_wsgi was built against. Suggest you use the mod_wsgi mailing list if need more explanation.

Comment: Also read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/11/save-on-memory-with-modwsgi-30.html and make sure you are turning off embedded mode if always delegating to daemon process mode.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I've understand both the no need to add the `vhosts_venv` and the need to add `WSGIRestrictEmbedded On`. Things work smooth now. If you'd like to write an "answer" ... I'd happy to mark it as "accepted". Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize Graham Dumpleton's answer

- mod_wsgi 4.5.4 was broken with Python3. 4.5.5 fixed it.
- It's possible to setup a Python virtualenv for the virtualhosting (with package `mod_wsgi`) but is recommended to setup a Python virtualenv using `python-home` option and not `python-path`.
- It's recommended to set `WSGIRestrictEmbedded On` according to http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/11/save-on-memory-with-modwsgi-30.html

`/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.conf` looks like :

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/vhost1.conf` looks like :

```
<VirtualHost vhost1.example.com:80>
  ServerName vhost1.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhost1_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhost1_access.log combined

  WSGIDaemonProcess vhost1.example.com threads=15 python-home=/home/admin/vhost1_venv python-path=/home/admin/vhost1
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/vhost1/vhost1/wsgi.py process-group=vhost1.example.com application-group=%{GLOBAL}

  <Directory /home/admin/vhost1>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      <IfVersion < 2.3>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
      </IfVersion>
      <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
      </IfVersion>
    </Files>
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```