# Django for windows, using WSGIPythonPath for multiple instances of Virtual Host

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, wsgi, production, django-wsgi

Im using Windows 10

In httpd.conf (Apache) how to use WSGIPythonPath for multiple instances of Virtual Host for different project and ports since WSGIDaemonProcess is not supported on Windows.

**httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/webdev/documents/mark/digos-logs/venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:\Users\WebDev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37"
WSGIPythonPath "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\digos-logs"
```

where "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\digos-logs" is my project root folder and "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark" is my parent folder of all my projects.

**Project 1**

```
listen 9292
<VirtualHost *:9292>
ServerName 127.0.0.1

# error occured (Example)
WSGIPythonPath "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\digos-logs"
######3


WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\digos-logs\app_ict\wsgi.py"

<Directory "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\digos-logs\app_ict">
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


DocumentRoot C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\digos-logs


<Directory "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\digos-logs\static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Project 2**

```
listen 9595
<VirtualHost *:9595>
ServerName 127.0.0.1

# error occured (Example)
WSGIPythonPath "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\project2"
######3


WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\project2\app\wsgi.py"

<Directory "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\project2\app">
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


DocumentRoot C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\project2


<Directory "C:\Users\WebDev\Documents\Mark\project2\static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: see my answer to this question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907416/how-should-i-add-wsgipython-path-in-virtualhost-for-windows-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907416/how-should-i-add-wsgipython-path-in-virtualhost-for-windows-server)

Comment: have you ever found a solution ?